# jquery getJSON recursive call

Tags: jquery, recursion, getjson, slickgrid

I have the following code for retrieving data from DB and setting up a grid.
Once I manipulate the grid, and saved in DB, I want the grid to be loaded again.
How do I call getJSON again to reload the data and the grid?

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON('/Test/GetData', function () {}).done(function () {
         //Load grid using data in jqxhr into grid
         //Manipulte data in grid and save in DB
         // At this point I want to call $.getJSON to refresh the grid
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
function loadData(repeat) {
  var jqxhr = $.getJSON('/Test/GetData', function () {}).done(function () {
    //Load grid using data in jqxhr into grid
    //Manipulte data in grid and save in DB
    // At this point I want to call $.getJSON to refresh the grid
    if (repeat) loadData(false);
  });
}
loadData(true);
```

This should loop one time.

Comment: sweet! tweaked it a little bit to fit my code a little bit. Thanks